# React: trigger code inside useEffect when condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next.js and I have a `layout.js` component that wraps the rest of my components.

I trying to trigger  the code in UseEffect when a component that contains a `div` with the id `#cartTotal` is mounted. At the moment the code only runs when the component that contains this div is refreshed.

I am sure it's just a case of checking if the variable value has changed but I am not quite sure how to do this.

I have tried to add `cartTotal` to the array but I get an error `cartTotal is not defined`

How can I get this code to run when a component that contains a `div` with the id `#cartTotal` is mounted within my `layout.js` file?

**layout.js**

```
  const [tagInvoiceNo, setTagInvoiceNo] = useState('')
  const [tagTotal,setTagTotal] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartTotal = document.querySelector('#cartTotal') !== null ? document.querySelector('#cartTotal').textContent.replace('£','') : ''
    const cartInvoiceNo = document.querySelector('#invoiceNo') !== null ? document.querySelector('#invoiceNo').textContent : ''
    
    if ((cartTotal &&!cartTotal.includes('}}')) && (cartInvoiceNo && !cartInvoiceNo.includes('}}'))) {
      setTagTotal(cartTotal)
      setTagInvoiceNo(cartInvoiceNo)
    }   
  },[])
```

Comment: If you remove the `[]` from the useEffect it will run on every render. I would avoid that though. You could use a context around the layout and have that component update it once its mounted

Comment: There are a couple of solutions I could think of - most simply, as @topched says, getting rid of the `[]` argument so that the effect runs every render. However, none are fully satisfactory. And the reason for this is that you are doing something that's fundamentally "un-React-like", in using the DOM Api to specifically look for elements. You don't show where the `#cartTotal` and `#invoiceNo` elements come from, but assuming they're controlled by React, you could easily use state to keep track of their presence and text content?

Comment: so I have a modal that contains the `#cartTotal` and `#invoiceNo` but this is a plugin written in vue that i've integrated so unfortunately that's why I'm hacking together a solution. Im not quite sure how I would use state to keep track of them? Wouldn't that be similar to what I have now?

Comment: and because the layout app doesn't re-render when the modal appears the useEffect never actually runs until the page is refreshed.